# It is possible to generate a match between an enumeration and the content of a vector

Tags: rust

What I am trying to do is to define values ​​within an enumeration with different types of data, and then fill those values ​​into a vector.
Then make a match between that vector and that enumeration so that it returns the value that the enumeration contains

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Types {
    Int(i32),
    Float(f64),
    Text(String),
}

fn main() {
    let type = vec![Types::Int(3),Types::Float(3.3),Types::Text("Hi".to_string())];
    println!("{:?}",&type[0]);
    //if let Types::Int(number) = &type[0] {println!("{:?}",number)}

    println!("{:?}",Types::Int(3));
    match &type {
        Types::Int(number) => number,
        Typer::Float(float) => float,
        _=> None,
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code cannot compile.

Besides the fact that you reuse the keyword `type` as a variable name, the return type of your match statement cannot be inferred.

In each of the arms of your match expression, the code returns different types. In the first, `i32`, in the second, `f64`, and in the third, an `Option` variant. This becomes more obvious if you tried to assign the result.

```rust
let foo: <????> = match &typ {
    Types::Int(number) => number,
    Types::Float(float) => float,
    _ => None,
};
```

What type should be inferred for `foo`? There is no consistent option, since it depends on the value of `typ` at *runtime*, and so cannot be used to define its type at *compile* time.

Luckly, the Rust compiler is awesome, and you see exactly this in an error message (after fixing the other issues).

```rust
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:16:32
   |
14 | /     match typ[0] {
15 | |         Types::Int(number) => number,
   | |                               ------ this is found to be of type `i32`
16 | |         Types::Float(float) => float,
   | |                                ^^^^^ expected `i32`, found `f64`
17 | |         _=> None,
18 | |     }
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types

error: aborting due to previous error
```